# Modify query to make timestamped entry even when no data found

Tags: mysql, date, insert

Is there a way to have this insert statement insert either a timestamped blank row or row will all 0's when no records are found based on the query? I am using this to display trending data on a graph and need timestamped records even if there is no data returned to keep this graph up to date.

Query:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT "SEM_AGENT"."DELETED"
  ,"PATTERN"."VERSION" 
  ,"PATTERN"."PATTERNDATE"
  ,"SEM_AGENT"."AGENT_VERSION"
  ,"SEM_CLIENT"."COMPUTER_NAME" "Computer Name"
  , "SEM_COMPUTER"."OPERATION_SYSTEM" "Operation System"
  ,dateadd(s,convert(bigint,"SEM_AGENT"."CREATION_TIME")/1000,'01-01-1970 00:00:00')     CREATION_DTTM
  , dateadd(s,convert(bigint,"SEM_AGENT"."LAST_UPDATE_TIME")/1000,'01-01-1970 00:00:00') Lastupdatetime
  , DATEADD(s, convert(bigint,LAST_SCAN_TIME)/1000, '01-01-1970 00:00:00')"Last Scan Time"
  , "PATTERN"."PATTERNDATE" "Pattern Date"
  , "SEM_CLIENT"."USER_NAME" "User Name"
  , "V_SEM_COMPUTER"."IP_ADDR1_TEXT" "IP Address"
  , "IDENTITY_MAP"."NAME" "Group Name"
FROM (((("SEM_AGENT" "SEM_AGENT" INNER JOIN "SEM_CLIENT" "SEM_CLIENT" 
  ON (("SEM_AGENT"."COMPUTER_ID"="SEM_CLIENT"."COMPUTER_ID") 
  AND ("SEM_AGENT"."DOMAIN_ID"="SEM_CLIENT"."DOMAIN_ID")) 
  AND ("SEM_AGENT"."GROUP_ID"="SEM_CLIENT"."GROUP_ID")) INNER JOIN "SEM_COMPUTER"   "SEM_COMPUTER" 
  ON (("SEM_AGENT"."COMPUTER_ID"="SEM_COMPUTER"."COMPUTER_ID") 
  AND ("SEM_AGENT"."DOMAIN_ID"="SEM_COMPUTER"."DOMAIN_ID")) 
  AND ("SEM_AGENT"."DELETED"="SEM_COMPUTER"."DELETED")) INNER JOIN "PATTERN" "PATTERN" 
  ON "SEM_AGENT"."PATTERN_IDX"="PATTERN"."PATTERN_IDX") INNER JOIN "IDENTITY_MAP"   "IDENTITY_MAP" 
  ON "SEM_CLIENT"."GROUP_ID"="IDENTITY_MAP"."ID") INNER JOIN "V_SEM_COMPUTER"   "V_SEM_COMPUTER" 
  ON "SEM_COMPUTER"."COMPUTER_ID"="V_SEM_COMPUTER"."COMPUTER_ID" 
  AND "SEM_AGENT"."DELETED"=0
WHERE Pattern.Patterndate < (select max(Patterndate) -2 from Pattern)
AND SEM_COMPUTER.OPERATION_SYSTEM NOT LIKE '%2000%'
ORDER BY "Computer Name"
```

Insert:

```
INSERT INTO av_internal (device_type, ip_address, user_tag, VERSION,     Computer_Name, Operation_System, Pattern_Date)

VALUES ("@Data.device_type~", "@Data.ip_address~", "@Data.user_tag~",    "@Data.VERSION~", "@Data.Computer_x0020_Name~", "@Data.Operation_x0020_System~", "@Data.PATTERNDATE~")
```

Here is the create table statement:

```
'av_Internal', 'CREATE TABLE `av_internal` (
  `device_type` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip_address` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_tag` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VERSION` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Computer_Name` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Operation_System` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Pattern_Date` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LAST_UPDATE` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1'
```

Comment: can you provide the create statement for the table you are inserting?

Answer (score 0):

Add a timestamp column in the table you are inserting called created_date and set it to have a default value of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Every record will then have the date it was created automagically added to the record.

Comment: I have a timestamp column. My question is how to add a timestamped blank row or row full of 0s when the above query returns no data. I need something in the table each time the insert statement runs, whether it be rows of data or just one blank row with a timestamp

Comment: @Ben you are setting the primary key to 0?

Comment: Here is the table structure:   device_type char(255) YES   
ip_address char(255) YES   
user_tag char(255) YES   --- I'm not familiar with the primary key. I am still learning all this.
VERSION char(255) YES   
Computer_Name char(255) YES   
Operation_System char(255) YES   
Pattern_Date char(255) YES   
LAST_UPDATE timestamp NO  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Comment: @Ben run this sql query: 'show create table tablename;' replace tablename with the name of your table and paste the results into the bottom of your question.

Comment: @Ben Can you add a column called id to this table?  Make it an auto incrementing primary key.  Then inserts will create new unique records.

Comment: Yes, I can add a column. Just want to make sure I have it right. Like this? ALTER TABLE av_internal ADD COLUMN `id` SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY

Comment: It is good practice to have a unique key for all non-linking tables

Comment: I added this in. I am just confused on how this will achieve the above. I ran the insert again and did not get any rows for today's date

Comment: The last update I am getting is from 6-29-12 (the last time there was data). I need to have some sort of timestamped row, even if there is no data each time the insert happens (it happens automatically via the BI platform I'm using)

Comment: @Ben sanity check... Run this query 'select now();'what is the result?

Comment: 18 rows of '2012-07-13 13:00:16' But if I select * I don't receive any results with today's date. Perhaps I now have to modify the query that is creating the chart to account for this?

Comment: @Ben i am guessing whatever is inserting into the table is explicitly specifying a value for your timesramp column in rhe insert statement.. That is the only way i can think of where the timestamp wouldn't be set.  If you come across another answer, shoot me a message because i am stumped!

Comment: @Ben unless there is a trigger or something doing some crazy funk on insert to the table...